# Moved hosts. Instead of reinstalling (which takes ages) copied all the files as well as the database. Now a lot of sites won't work

Tags: magento-1.9, database, migration

Good morning.
I'm still pretty new to Magento since I started using it not too long ago.
My company had to change webhosts because our previous host didn't have Cronjobs.
Now after moving all the files, a lot of sites won't open.
[This](http://www.wein-partner.at/shop/) is the site. 
The backend also changed from url/admin to url/index.php/admin for some reason.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

edit04:
When I first installed Magento onto the server, I had to clear all .htaccess files because they had something in them that was not compatible with our host. But since then it has been working fine. Whatever fine is in this case. At least the backend doesn't give me any trouble.

edit01:
That's how my .htaccess looks right now:

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
```

edit02:
If I add the .htaccess file into main directory, the site stops working.
(Unless it changes back to url/admin)
In the config/web the "use server rewrites" option is on

edit03:
So it does not just change back to url/admin.
This is what happens everytime I add the .htaccess file into "magento/"

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: it seems your .htaccess has some issue, please use original .htaccess from magento package and then test again

Comment: overwrote the .htaccess file in the root directory with the original-magento-install one. After that I cannot even go into backend. If I delete or empty the file however it works again. I quote from the world4you FAQ: "Entries like Options, php_flag, php_value etc. are not allowed and have to be deleted."

Comment: so, uncomment `Options +FollowSymLinks` from .htaccess and test

Comment: I had to delete a lot of php_flags.
Now it's working again.
"## enable rewrites | 
    Options +FollowSymLinks | 
    RewriteEngine on | I removed the Options-line

Comment: only uncomment `Options +FollowSymLinks` and test, do not delete anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your new server.
Let's take the registration page for example:

`http://www.wein-partner.at/shop/customer/account/create/` does not work, but 
`http://www.wein-partner.at/shop/index.php/customer/account/create/` does.

So I'm 99% sure that `mod_rewrite` is the issue here.

Comment: I agree with what @Marius is saying. Make sure your AllowOverride directive is set correctly i.e ALL http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: so basically I have to add into my .htaccess:
"AllowOverride All"?
Is that correct?

Comment: @theHubi. Not only that. You need to make sure that the `mod_rewrite` apache (if you are using apache) module is enabled. Here is how you can check if it's enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php and here are some details on what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: well if I log into our host I get:
"MySQL Databases" I can log into the database used for Magento and have phpMyAdmin from there on

Comment: if it helps, the new host is world4you.com

Answer (score -2):

Ok so everything works again!
Thanks everyone!

I owe you one.

summary:

> editing the .htaccess file and enabling RewriteEngine + checking the config/web for rewrite was successful.

**/closed/**